# mic left and mic right to single TRRS mic

Tags: audio, microphone

how to connect mic left and mic right to single TRRS mic connection. The first figure shows mic left and mic right connected to microphone output jack. I want to replace this output jack with the TRRS jack as shown in figure 2. the second figure shows Ring2 as the mic connection.

[image: mic left and mic right]
[image]

Comment: so, you want to combine the left and right mic signals into a single mic signal (like might be used on a smartphone or tablet)?

Answer (score 1):

You can leave RING2 unconnected or you can connect it to sleeve. The second option means it will work on both three or four-wire cables.

```
3-pin            4-pin
Tip ------------ Tip
Ring ----------- Ring1
              +- Ring2
Sleeve -------+- Sleeve
```

By the way, the figure does not show RING2 as the mic connection.